# SharePoint 2010: Blog post alerts

Tags: sharepoint-2010, alert

When creating an alert to a single blog post, I would have *assumed* that you would receive a notification email each time a comment was left on that post. **This is not the case.**

The alert will only notify you of any changes that are made to the actual item in the Posts list (e.g. if you alter the text in the Title or Body fields).

Does anyone know a nice way to go about creating an alert to notify the user whenever a comment has been left on the post? Ideally, I'm looking to replicate the behaviour here on stackoverflow where you can be alerted when anyone adds comments or answers to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that Raymund listed works for individual blogs.

We needed it for each and every blog though, so I wrote an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) and used [Feature Stapling](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/introduction-to-sharepoint-feature-stapling-part-1) to attach it to the blog site template. This way, everytime someone posts a comment I look up which posting the comment was made against, lookup the creator of that post, and send them an email.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStum you pointed me in the right direction... I really wanted to use the **alert framework** so that my users could manage and personalise the notifications themselves via their My Site. I ended up using an EventReceiver to automatically create an alert on the Comments list each time a blog post was created. The trick here was to set the **SPAlert.Filter** property of each alert with `<Eq><FieldRef Name="PostTitle"/><Value type="string">PostTitle</Value></Eq>`. This ensures that the alert gets triggered only when a comment is added to **their blog post**.

Comment: @Nick That is actually an awesome solution, haven't looked into Alert Filters but that's useful!

Answer (score 1):

Blog Comments are treated as lists in Sharepoint

[image]

if you create a workflow when an item is added to that list to email you on create and/or change then your requirement is satisfied. You will need Sharepoint Designer on this one. Let me know if you need assistance I will show you step by step procedures if you want.

Comment: Raymund, found your answer here and wrote a short List Workflow on the Comments list on the Blog site within mysite. The last action of this short workflow sends an email. In the "Define Email Message" dialog, the To: address is hardcoded to johna@cbmiweb.com and the CC: is hardcoded to johnadams41@gmail.com. Both are legit and yet I only get the email sent to gmail.com. Other workflows in this farm have successfully sent email to someuser@cbmiweb.com. This blog happens to be in a different web application (port 81 versus port 80). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OOB alert functionality built into SharePoint. Just setup an alert on the comments list. You can do this with an Event Receiver and Feature Stapling as well.

Comment: Hi Doug, thank-you for your advice. I've created an event receiver which triggers when a new item is added to the Posts list. I use this to create an alert on the Comments list (for the post's author). I've also created a feature to deploy my event receiver and successfully stapled it to the site definition. My only question is this: the Comments list contains the comments on *ALL* the blog posts -- how do I set up an alert on that list to only trigger when a comment gets left for a particular post?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure that you could do this for just a specific blog post, unless you added a column to indicate this. Why do you only want to do this for comments to a specific blog post. I would think that you would want to do this for all to be consistent.

Comment: I'll give an example... If three **seperate users** each create a blog post (let's say their titles are "Post-A", "Post-B" and "Post-C") each author will automatically get an alert created for them on the Comments list. All good so far. If I then come along and leave a single comment on "Post-A", all three authors get notified of the comment -- even though the comment was only relevant to the author of "Post-A". This is becuase the alert states *"Notify users immediately when new items are added to the Comments list"*. I only want the author of "Post-A" to get the notification.

Comment: I misunderstood the scenario. I thought this was a personal blog site setup within a my site. Since you are dealing with a blog where multiple people can contribute, you will need to setup an event receiver that sends the email to the creator of the blog post like Michael Stum indicates above.